# Command/script in unix to convert mainframe ebcdic file in ascci

Tags: unix

I am trying to convert mainframe ebcdic file in ascii format. Can someone help me with the command or script in unix to achieve this.

Comment: Do you have `iconv`  or `recode` commands?

Comment: I have iconv and tried using this. But it is still giving unreadable data after conversion. I dont have recode in my unix

Comment: Please show the exact `iconv` command you used and tell us what exactly means "unreadable data". What are the character encodings before and after the conversion? I suggest to create a small input file that contains the problematic data and show a hex dump of input and output. If the input file contains characters that are not part of ASCII you probably need a different output encoding, e.g.  UTF-8 or ISO_8859-1.

Comment: I used command iconv -f EBCDIC -t ASCII test.bin > output.txt . When i do this the output file is having unreadable data. The mainframe EBCDIC bin file is generated from Informatica. We have used encoding=EBCDIC and codepage=IBM 037 while generating the bin file. sorry, I work for one of bank customer so will not be able to put any data here.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add all information there. If you can't show a short snippet of your original file, create a sample file that contains the problematic data. Something like "hello world <your problematic data> goodbye world" that can reproduce your problem. Otherwise we cannot tell why you might get unreadable data.

Answer (score 2):

One classic way uses [`dd`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/dd.1.html):

```
dd if=ebcdicfile.txt of=asciifile.txt conv=ascii
```

Or [`iconv`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/iconv.1.html):

```
iconv -f ebcdicus -t ascii ebcdicfile.txt > asciifile.txt
```

(You might have to play with /which/ EBCDIC for `iconv` - it has a lot of variations; see `iconv --list | grep EBCDIC` for the complete list.)

Comment: Thank you Shawn. As i said i used these commands but no luck.